# Javascript inside jQuery replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP script that generates some jQuery and replaceWith() to change some some tags (figure tag -> div).  This small script that is generated by PHP has dynamic content.  It works as expected, except when the PHP script generates javascript - then I get errors.

For example....

```
<figure class=“class”>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery( 'figure' ).replaceWith('<div><script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.js"></script></div>'); 
</script>   
</figure>
```

This gives me an error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Can I use javascript inside replaceWith?

Comment: Have you tried going to the resource being pulled in on that script tag to see if you get the same error?

Comment: It is a script from JWPlayer and works when I load it without using replaceWith.

Comment: In the console, what is throwing this error? Look for a line number and file. It'd be helpful to know if it's coming from the code you wrote to load the file or the file itself. Also, have you tried loading a simpler script, such as something that just alerts or prints to the console?

Comment: It is the line that is generated that is throwing the error.  Chrome dev tools shows the error (red underline) starting right after replaceWith(  - I will try a basic javascript see if it does the same.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery( 'figure' ).replaceWith("<div><script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello World");</script></div>"); </script> - this also throws an error.

Comment: @ChrisHawkins that one doesn't escape quotes correctly

Comment: Escaping on that has worked.  Guess I have to escape the string (which generates the <script></script> that PHP generates.